# Merge dataframes by the nearest lower or equal date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
    'Date':['31.08.2023', '12.09.2023', '13.09.2023', '20.08.2023']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
        'Date':['30.08.2023', '14.09.2023', '10.09.2023', '28.09.2023', '19.08.2023']})
```

I want to add two new columns to df1 with the nearest higher and lower date in every ID, so the desire output in this example will look like this:

| ID | DATE | DATE_UP | DATE_DOWN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 31.08.2023 | 10.09.2023 | 30.08.2023 |
| A | 12.09.2023 | 14.09.2023 | 10.09.2023 |
| B | 13.09.2023 | 28.09.2023 | 19.08.2023 |
| B | 20.08.2023 | 28.09.2023 | 19.08.2023 |

I know there is a pandas function merge_asof(), but it work only for the nearest merge.
I will be greatfull for any ideas how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

you can solve it by `merge_asof`. merge_asof doesnt work only for the nearest merge. Even nearest is not the default, the default is backward.

---

at first make datetime column named 'Date1' and sort

```
df1['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df1 = df1.sort_values('Date1')
df2['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df2 = df2.sort_values('Date1')
```

df1:

```
    ID  Date        Date1
3   B   20.08.2023  2023-08-20
0   A   31.08.2023  2023-08-31
1   A   12.09.2023  2023-09-12
2   B   13.09.2023  2023-09-13
```

df2:

```
    ID  Date        Date1
4   B   19.08.2023  2023-08-19
0   A   30.08.2023  2023-08-30
2   A   10.09.2023  2023-09-10
1   A   14.09.2023  2023-09-14
3   B   28.09.2023  2023-09-28
```

---

next use `merge_asof` forward & backward(default)

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(), df2, on='Date1', by='ID', 
                    direction='forward', suffixes=['', '_up'])
out = pd.merge_asof(tmp, df2, on='Date1', by='ID', suffixes=['', '_down'])\
        .drop('Date1', axis=1).set_index('index').sort_index().rename_axis('')
```

out:

```
    ID  Date        Date_up     Date_down
0   A   31.08.2023  10.09.2023  30.08.2023
1   A   12.09.2023  14.09.2023  10.09.2023
2   B   13.09.2023  28.09.2023  19.08.2023
3   B   20.08.2023  28.09.2023  19.08.2023
```